# How can I create playlist in android using MediaStore?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-contentprovider

I know this has been asked many times before.
That's why I'm really sorry for asking.

[this is what I was looking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10969281/how-to-create-a-new-playlist-using-contentresolver])

I want to know: How can I get the playlist's id ?
I think the id is not created because the playlist has not been created yet.
The id is needed to add the playlist.....
So what should I do...?